# Чтение отдельных слов в string

Tags: c++, строки

Можно ли читать отдельные слова в строке `string`, типо как `scanf("%s%s")`?

Comment: можно, причем это можно делать посредством той же `sscanf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос задан так, что можно прочесть его по-разному.

Первое прочтение - читать слова из стандартного ввода в строки. Это проще всего делать просто как

```
string a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
```

То же самое, что и чтение отдельных слов с помощью `scanf`.

Второе прочтение - читать слова из некоторой строки в строки. Тут, пожалуй, проще всего воспользоваться `istringstream`. Итак, у вас есть строка `s`, в которой много слов. Тогда можно сделать так:

```
istringstream in(s);
string a, b;
in >> a >> b;
```